# Web Parts not aligning correctly on page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, page-layout

I am having an issue with a page layout in SharePoint 2013 that I just can’t seem to get right. I have blank welcome page that I want 3 web part zones to sit on side by side
[image: side by side]

I created a table with one row, used the snippet gallery to create 3 web part zones and placed them between the TD’s. The page displays the zones correctly but when I add web parts to them they get all out of whack and won’t stay aligned at the top

[image]

my code is:

```
<div data-name="WebPartZone">
    <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--Start Table to hold three column web part-->
           <div xmlns:ie="ie">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div data-name="WebPartZone">
                <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Top_Left" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                        <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                            <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
                </div>
                <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div data-name="WebPartZone">
            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Center" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                    <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                        <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                    <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
            </div>
            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div data-name="WebPartZone">
            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Top_Right" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                    <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                        <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                    <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
            </div>
            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
        </div>
        </div></div>
                <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
                <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">-->
                    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>-->
                <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an attribute to the TR tag:  vAlign=top

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden content editor webpart above each and give it zone index 0. Set your other webparts to zone index 1.